# Error when running a python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros

I am trying to run a script using an interface created with **tkinter**. I have a button that executes a script which code is:

```
subprocess.call("python3 " + PATH_TO_SCRIPTS + "main.py 1 &", shell=True)
```

However, when this button is pressed I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/m//PycharmProjects/ROSAutonomousFlight/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_numeric_method_controller/scripts/main.py", line 17, in <module>
      from controller import *
    File "/home/m/PycharmProjects/ROSAutonomousFlight/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_numeric_method_controller/scripts/controller.py", line 5, in <module>
      import rospy
```

It says that the module rospy does not exist, but when I run
import rospy 
using python or python3 it is imported successfully. What can I do to solve this issue? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Where does `rospy.py` exist? Is it there in your `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: Can you show the structure in which `rospy` exists, compared to `main.py` ?

Comment: this is what I have in main.py `from controller import *`, and this `import rospy`  is what I have in controller.py both py files are in the same directory. There is more code but here is where I am getting the error.

Comment: Could this be of any help : http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Troubleshooting

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf To check your path, you can use import sys and then print sys.path

Comment: I have done that, and I have obtained `['/home/m/PycharmProjects/ROSAutonomousFlight/catkin_ws/src/ardrone_numeric_method_controller/scripts', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/m/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', `

Comment: `'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments to your question are mostly about Python, but I guess it is more of a ROS issue.

You don't have to set-up your PYTHONPATH manually to find `rospy` but you have to source the `setup.bash` of your catkin workspace (otherwise none of the ROS tools is found).

Usually this is done by adding something like

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

to `.bashrc`. This works fine for everything that is run **in a terminal**.

I don't know how you start your script but as it provides a graphical interface you probably just run it by double-clicking it in the file browser? If you indeed do so, the script is *not* run in a terminal and therefore can't find the ROS modules. Run the script from a terminal (in which the `setup.bash` has been sourced) and it should work.